# Fetching data from CoreData with multiple Entities

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a data model that has 2 entities Person and Photo, they have have Attributes named `name` how can I be sure when using a `NSPredicate` that I will fetch or evaluate information from the correct entity if I'm looking by `name`?

This would be my current `NSPredicate` but I'm really unsure on the issue:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", [currItem objectForKey:@"user"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set the appropriate entity on the `NSFetchRequest` that you're using to fetch the entities.  The name field would correspond to the name field on whatever entity you set.

Comment: But what if I don't wanna fetch the entity? Just use the predicate's evaluateWithObject method?

Comment: All fetch request are locked to a specific entity against which the fetch request's predicate is evaluated. That is true regardless of the other configurations of the fetch. There are no other means of using a predicate to find objects in a context. It's a fetch request or nothing.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was misreading the code example somewhat, now I get it.